# Excel - Minimum Number of Required Fields

Tags: excel

I am creating a form in Excel where user will have to fill minimum 3/4 of fields but not all of them. If he fills enough fields the output will be the average value of all the fields. If not it needs to show him some error text.

Does someone know how/if this can be done? Here are the examples:

Example 1:

```
Field 1: Value 1
Field 2: Value 2
Field 3: Value 3
Field 4: Value 4
Result: Average of all 4 fields
```

Example 2:

```
Field 1: Value 1
Field 2: Value 2
Field 3: Value 3
Field 4: Empty
Result: Average of 3 fields
```

Example 3:

```
Field 1: Value 1
Field 2: Value 2
Field 3: Empty
Field 4: Empty
Result: Error Text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the UserForm's code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim cCont As Control
Dim Sum As Double, Count As Integer

Sum = 0
Count = 0

For Each cCont In Me.Controls

    If TypeName(cCont) = "TextBox" Then
        If IsNumeric(cCont.Text) Then
            Sum = Sum + cCont.Text
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    End If

Next cCont

If Count > 2 Then
    MsgBox "Average of all " & Count & " fields: " & Sum / Count
Else
    MsgBox "Error Text"
End If

End Sub
```